# How to load the content of each page in OpenCart 3 after full page load (javascript)?

Tags: php, optimization, opencart, opencart-3

I would appreciate it if someone can point me into the right direction on this issue.

I'm trying to optimize page load speed of my OpenCart project. To do this I want to load the content of each page (`product/category` , `product/search`, ...) after javascript onload like this in header.twig:

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log('page loaded');

    $.post( window.location.href, { loaded: true })
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: ");
    });
}
```

In php side I tried such a code but it's not successful at all.

```
if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id']) && isset($_POST['loaded'])) {
...
```

If I want to use `callback` the problem is pages are different. I don't know how to manage all pages.

Comment: Can you please clarify what this means "*the problem is pages are different*"?  What is your question?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand, how will this optimize page load speed? As the routes/pages are different you can try to do the above php logic in `index.php` directly but, its going to be too complicated to handle. Instead handle it individually.

Comment: @RohitBatra: Actually I already tried to apply it individually and it's successful.

Comment: @Kardo so where is the problem then? Are you trying to have one common `callback` function for all the pages ?

Comment: @RohitBatra: The time I asked this question I didn't have any idea how to do it, but little later the idea you explained came to my mind. I tried it last night. It works, but unfortunately it's not stable. Very often it passes over the `window.onload = function() {...`. The result is a blank page (www.bindex.co) Right now I'm trying to fix this. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @RohitBatra: Interesting. Javascript doesn't allow more than window.onload

Comment: @Kardo did you try `$(window).on('load', function() {` also?

Comment: @RohitBatra: Now everything works fine. I just removed extra `window.onload`

Comment: @Kardo can you update the above code, with the working one. It will be helpful for others who maybe trying this too.

Comment: @RohitBatra: I added it as answer, to be more helpful :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

To fix the issue I removed all `window.onload = function()`s from header, footer, etc. Instead, I added it to `common/home`, `product/search`, etc, and it works fine.

```
window.onload = function() {

var productClass = 'product-layout product-full col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12';

$('#moreHolder').css("display", "block");

$.post('index.php?route=product/productx', { class: productClass },
function(data) {
     if(data.length>10){
        $(data).insertBefore($('#moreHolder'));
     }
})
.always(function() {
    $('#moreHolder').css("display", "none");
});
```

I also added `swiper` related `style` and `javascript` on each page's first load, checking it by the number of `products/limit = page` to not have duplicates:

```
{% if products %} 
{% if page <= 1 %} 
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/swiper/css/opencart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/swiper/js/swiper.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endif %} 
{% for product in products %}
....
```